# Перетягивание View

Tags: android

Нашел пример кода с реализацией Drag&Drop, почти все понял, остались некоторые непонятные моменты.

Есть контейнер (ImageView4) и 3 картинки(ImageView1-3). Мы можем захватить и перетянуть любую из трех картинок. Если при отпускании окажется что картинка над контейнером, то она в нем и останется, иначе вернется на свою начальную позицию.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    View selectedItem = null;
    int offSetX = 0;
    int offSetY = 0;
    boolean touchFlag = false, dropFlag= false;
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageParams;
    ImageView imageView4, imageView1, imageView2, imageView3;
    int ex, ey;
    int topY, leftX, rightX, bottomY;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate begin");
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        root.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate onTouch begin");
                if (touchFlag) {
                    Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate onTouch if begin");
                    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate ACTION_DOWN begin");
                            //определяем коордынаты прямоугольника
                            topY = imageView4.getTop();
                            leftX = imageView4.getLeft();
                            rightX = imageView4.getRight();
                            bottomY = imageView4.getBottom();
                            Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate ACTION_DOWN end");
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate ACTION_UP begin");
                            touchFlag = false;
                            if (dropFlag) {
                                dropFlag = false;
                            } else {
                                selectedItem.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
                            }
                            Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate ACTION_DOWN end");
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate ACTION_MOVE begin");
                            ex = (int) event.getX();
                            ey = (int) event.getY();
                            int x = (int) event.getX()-offSetX;
                            int y = (int) event.getY()-offSetY;
                            Log.d("MyLogs", "ex = " + ex + " ey = " + ey);
                            Log.d("MyLogs", "x = " + x + " y = " + y);
                            //int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()-50;
                            //int y = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()-50;
                            DisplayMetrics disp = new DisplayMetrics();//метод позволяет узнать размеры экрана
                            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(disp);
                            int screenWi = disp.widthPixels;
                            int screenHei = disp.heightPixels;

                            if (x > screenWi) {
                                x = screenWi;
                            }
                            if (y > screenHei) {
                                y = screenHei;
                            }

                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams il = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                            il.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
                            //проверка что отпустили картинку в пределах прямоугольника
                            if(ex>leftX && ex<rightX && ey>topY&&ey<bottomY) {
                                imageView4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                selectedItem.bringToFront();
                                dropFlag = true;
                            } else {
                                imageView4.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            }
                            selectedItem.setLayoutParams(il);
                            Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate ACTION_MOVE end");
                            break;
                    }
                    Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate onTouch if end");
                }
                Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate onTouch end");
                return true;
            }
        });
        imageView1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        imageView2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        imageView3.setOnTouchListener(this);
        Log.d("MyLog", "onCreate end");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("MyLog", "onTouch begin");
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("MyLog", "onTouch ACTION_DOWN begin");
                touchFlag = true;
                offSetX = (int) event.getX();
                offSetY = (int) event.getY();
                selectedItem = v;
                imageParams = v.getLayoutParams();
                Log.d("MyLogs", "offSetX = " + offSetX + " offSetY = " + offSetY);
                Log.d("MyLog", "onTouch ACTION_DOWN end");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d("MyLog", "onTouch ACTION_UP begin");
                selectedItem = null;
                touchFlag = false;
                Log.d("MyLog", "onTouch ACTION_UP end");
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        Log.d("MyLog", "onTouch end");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/p4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/p2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/p3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/p1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Все просто, единственное - правильно ли я понимаю, что из-за того, что в методе **OnTouch** возвращается **false** мы сообщаем системе что данный метод отработал не до конца, или неправильно, а поэтому обработку этого события следует поручить другому обработчику, поэтому она поручает это дело **"обработчику касания для всего окна"** , который мы создали уже в **onCreate**??

Тоесть сначала **обработчик конкретно созданный для нашей картинки**, а потом уже **"обработчик для всего окна"**.

Если это так, то  почему же тогда когда мы отпускаем палец, то сразу же срабатывает "обработчик для всего окна", почему не по той же схеме что и с **ACTION_DOWN** ? Проверял по логам.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код вообще не о D&D, а о перемещении пальца по экрану.

Вот подробный официальный туториал.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Вкратце:
- вешаете `View.OnLongClickListener` на элемент, который хотите перемещать.
- Создаете "тень" элемента и вызвав `startDrag` у элемента, этим сообщаете системе что его перемещаем.
- Ловите события `View.OnDragListener` и реагируете на них.

Давно последний раз делал, но все работало как надо.